# Integration Testing on Rails 2.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration, integration-testing

At my work we are currently on Rails 2.1 and we need to do more integration testing. Our problem is that the Cucumber version which works with our rails version does not test the javascript on the page because we don't have Rack/Capybara. We stopped using Selenium because it was incredibly slow.

I was looking into EnvyJS, I don't know if there is a solution for that.

Is there a solution to test our web pages with javascript?

Answer (score -1):

If this app is exposed to the internet then all your efforts need to go into upgrading to Rails 2.3 immediately.  The security vulnerability at http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/ is such that any server with an app running an unpatched version of Rails *will* be auto-pwned to all privileges that the ruby process has via automated script-kiddie exploit.  It's only a matter of time.

Aside from that Rails development generally gets quite painful once you fall out of the sweet spot of maintained versions and you start spending more and more time rolling your own solutions to problems that have already been fixed.  This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but I doubt anyone will have a better one because all our effort is going into newer versions. For long-term stability of versions, Ruby, and Rails in particular is one of the worst language choices.